# Conformally flat transformation of a metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'd like a hint for the following exercise: Find a conformally flat transformation for the 2D metric of the sphere $$g=d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}(\theta)d\phi^{2}.$$ Or at least some bibliography. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic It's from my G.R. course but you're right, I could post it there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way is the following. Observe that
$$\sin^{-2} \theta \: g = \left(\frac{d\theta}{\sin \theta} \right)^2 + d\phi^2\:.$$
This identity suggests to define the new coordinate 
$$\xi = \int  \frac{d\theta}{\sin \theta} = \ln \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}{1+\cos \theta}} \:,\quad \theta \in (0,\pi)$$
Notice that coordinates $\xi, \phi$ with $\phi \in (-\pi, \pi)$ and $\xi\in (-\infty, +\infty)$ cover the sphere up to the poles (assuming the identification $-\pi=\pi$ for the coordinate $\phi$) exactly as the standard coordinates $\theta, \phi$ do.

Summing up, if $\Omega = \sin^{-1} \theta$,
$$\Omega^2 g = d\xi^2 + d\phi^2\:.$$
The right-hand side is the flat metric in $\mathbb R^2$ or, if one preserves the identification $-\pi \equiv \pi$ for $\phi$, it is the flat metric on a cylinder immersed in $\mathbb R^3$. This proves that the $2$-spheres **minus its two poles** is conformally equivalent to a flat $2$-cylinder.

Comment: Ok I get that you wrote the metric as follows: $g=sin^{2}(\theta)[(\frac{d\theta}{sin(\theta)})^{2}+d\phi^{2}]$ but then how do you get it to the numerator of the left hand side? I get $\frac{g}{sin^{2}(\theta)}$=RHS.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted a sign in the exponent! Now it should be correct.

Comment: Following the link from the user "AccidentalFouriertransform" to wikipedia it says that $\tilde{g}=e^{2\phi}g$ where $\phi$ is a smooth, real valued function. But to express the sine in terms of the exponent, you have to use imaginary numbers. So how do you do that?

Comment: Nope. $e^{2\phi}= \Omega^2 = 1/\sin^2 \theta$ so that $\phi = - \ln \sin \theta$ which is real for $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ because $\sin \theta \in (0,1]$ in that case.